# Change to Facebook Canvas URL occassionally using old URL

Tags: canvas, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I recently updated the Canvas URL in my Facebook App, I changed it from www.domainname.com/subdir/ to sub-fb.domainname.com/.  For some reason it will randomly switch between the 2 urls on different visits.  Is there some kind of Facebook cache that needs to be cleared?  I made the change 2 days ago.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you changed both _canvas url_ and _secure canvas url_ ?

Comment: the secure canvas url is blank, it has never had a value set there

Comment: That doesn't answer your question but [Secure URL will be needed when publishing your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/). Give us more details (screens or links) please.

Comment: this ended up being an issue with facebook caching, just had to wait it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ended up being an issue with facebook round-robin caching, just had to wait it out

Comment: Any url for this information? Where can we know if the problem is solved?